# How to preserve edge grading of rotated edges in ICEM CFD?

Tags: cfd, meshing

I have a 2D axisymmetric geometry for which I am generating block-structured mesh in ICEM. I am converting this 2D block setup to a 3D block setup by rotating the 2D blocks using a dedicated option in ICEM.

I have noticed that the edge grading consisting of growth ratios and linked edges in 2D is not preserved when the blocks are rotated to 3D.

I specifically want to use this approach because keeping a track of blocks and associations in 3D model is too complicated and time consuming. The 2D  to 3D pathway helps me a lot but I lose the grading information I generated in 2D. Doing the grading in 3D mode is time consuming.

Ideally, this grading should be preserved when the rotation is done.

How can I solve this problem ?